# Changed table values for mysql but cloudbees still uses old values

Tags: java, mysql, database, playframework, cloudbees

I got this error in my logs when I uploaded my app to cloudbees

```
[[31merror[0m] play - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'desc                      varchar(255),
kind                      varchar(255),
' at line 4 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000]
```

After some googling and browsing questions on SO I figured that the problem was that desc is a keyword in mysql and not in H2, so I changed desc to description and re-deployed my app. But now I get the exact same error with desc again. Do I have to execute the evolution scripts manually to overwrite those values or something?

Comment: you may need to run migrations again - from your desktop

Comment: ie, you may need to undo the evolution and apply it again.

Comment: You may also want to try the https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework for play specific questions - not sure how heavily trafficed the playframework tag here is (of course cloudbees one is used heavily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your migrations - firstly to undo the migration that made the change, and then to re apply it - this is a play specific feature, nothing to do with cloudbees.

Comment: Alright thanks, Ill ask on the play group then about how to do such a thing. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction

Comment: no problems - I only recently learned about evolutions myself with play.